# Authorization based on creator

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Lets assume we have an ASP.NET MVC blogging app that allows users to register and then blog on the site. Now lets assume that the blog edit page takes in the blogId and then presents the information related to the blog. In the action method how can we ensure that the BlogId that is received by the action method is the one that the logged in user has created? We can have a scenario where someone could modify the URL and put in an ID for a blog that does not belong to the logged in user. What is the best way of preventing this?

One option that I can think of is getting the creator of the blog in the action method and then checking it against the ID of the logged in user to ensure that the user has access to edit that specific blog. Can this be achieved by some kind of filter rather than having to specify this in the action method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can this be achieved by some kind of filter rather than having to
>   specify this in the action method ?

Of course. You could write a custom authorize attribute:

```
public class AuthorizeBlogPostOwnerAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var authorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        if (!authorized)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var user = httpContext.User;

        var rd = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData;
        var id = rd.Values["postid"] as string;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return IsOwnerOfBlogPost(user.Identity.Name, id);
    }

    private bool IsOwnerOfPost(string username, string postId)
    {
        // hit your dabatase here and validate if the current user
        // is owner of the blog post
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

that could be used to decorate your controller action:

```
[AuthorizeBlogPostOwner]
public ActionResult SomeAction(string postId)
{
    ... if we got that far it means that the current user is owner of the blog post
}
```